# How to find merge commits from topic branch

Tags: git, merge

I'm in the release branch that has a few `merge --no-ff feature` at different points in time.

The output of `git log --first-parent` (conceptually) looks like this:

```
 git checkout release
 git log --oneline --first-parent

 C1 Merge branch feature <--- release HEAD
 C2 Merge branch some other thing
 C3 Merge branch hotfix
 C4 Merge branch etc
 C5 Merge branch feature
 C6 ...
```

I'm looking for a way to get the following output:

```
 C1
 C5
```

All merges where created with `git merge --no-ff`.

Comment: You can just use the double dot notation: `git log --merges feature..release`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not the best defined ever, but consider:

```
git log --merges --first-parent --grep feature
```

which has the advantage of being simple.  The `--merges` retains only merge commits; the `--first-parent` follows only first-parent links; and the `--grep feature` searches the commit message text for the word "feature".

Alternatively, to solve a somewhat different problem, you could attempt to select commits that are:

1. merge commits (have at least two parents);
2. reachable from `HEAD`; and
3. reachable from the current tip of `feature`

but there's no syntax for that.  The `git rev-list` command can select commits that are merges and are reachable from any given point, but it only does disjunctions (union / "or").  (This is one of the places Mercurial's revision selection syntax beats Git's.)  You would have to use `git rev-list` twice, once to get each list, and then use another program (`comm` being the obvious one) to find the intersection of the two sets.

Comment: I was looking for those `git rev-list` commands. I thought I could do the intersection somehow just with git commands. I've noticed that `git log --merges --pretty=%P` will show the parents of each commit in the `release` branch. I guess I need to `cut` the parent column out and query that against the `feature` branch to see if they only exist there, meaning they were merged from that branch.